# Change row order in a matrix/dataframe with pipes

Tags: r, matrix

I have some matrix or dataframe

```
m <- matrix(1:6, ncol=2)
```

..

```
m
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    3    6
```

i need to change order rows in a line with pipes, something like this

```
m |> m[nrow(m):1, ]
```

but of course it doesn't work..

I know that I can do this using the dplyr package

```
library(dplyr)
m  |> as.data.frame() |> arrange(-row_number())
```

But I'm wondering how to do this with base R.

Comment: One completely pointless option - `m |> (\(x) x[nrow(x):1,])()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `i=` and `j=` operators of the bracket function.

```
m |> base::`[`(3:1, )
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    3    6
# [2,]    2    5
# [3,]    1    4
```

Generalized:

```
m |> base::`[`(dim(m)[1]:1, )
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    3    6
# [2,]    2    5
# [3,]    1    4
```

<sub>Note: Contributions also come from *@thelatemail* and *@ThomasIsCoding*.</sub>

---

*Data:*

```
m <- structure(1:6, dim = 3:2)
```

Comment: I guess you can simply apply ``m |> base::`[`(nrow(m):1, )``

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding TY, letting `j` default was actually obvious and removed overhead, your comma did the trick! `dim` is faster than `nrow`.

Comment: That's new to me - I didn't know you could just call `m |> base::\`[\`(1)` to get around the error of `m |> \`[\`(1)` .

Comment: @thelatemail Don't think it's official, actually it's a hack.

Answer (score 2):

The RHS of the base-R `|>` pipe *must* be a function, you can't use `m[...]` on the RHS at all. However ... `` `[`(..) `` (despite being a function call) explicitly does not work (`Error: function '[' not supported in RHS call of a pipe`).

A (hasty, untested) hack-function might be:

```r
fn <- function(x, i=NULL, j=NULL) x[if (is.null(i)) seq_len(nrow(x)) else i, if (is.null(j)) seq_len(ncol(x)) else j]
m |>
  fn(nrow(m):1)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    3    6
# [2,]    2    5
# [3,]    1    4
```

... though I'm sure there are corner-cases where this may not work perfectly.